# How to send integer and string array JSON data to server using Volley in android

Tags: android, json, android-volley

**This is my ItemDetailActivity**

Here I have specified both integer and string value. As my main task is to calculate total value which can be obtained when I multiply the price with quantity, to do so I have to convert the string value into integer so I can perform multiplication and the below code has worked for me when I tried to pass only string value but as I convert them into integer it sends value but except 'Items' value which I have specified as string only stores in database and remaining 'total, price and quantity' which are specified as integer stores as '0' (zero). Can I have some idea that how I can I send the data if there is both string and integer value presented?

```
 itemname = Itemname.getText().toString();
 price = Integer.parseInt(Price.getText().toString());
 quantity = Integer.parseInt(Integer.toString(count));
 total = price * quantity;

 StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, server_url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    Toast.makeText(ItemDetailActivity.this, " "+itemname+" is added to your cart", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    Toast.makeText(ItemDetailActivity.this, "Some error went wrong!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    error.printStackTrace();
                }
            }){
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {

                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                    Map<String, Integer> param2 = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
                    params.put("Items",itemname);
                    param2.put("Price",price);
                    param2.put("Quantity",quantity);
                    param2.put("Total",total);

                    return params;
                }
            };

            MySingleton.getmInstance(ItemDetailActivity.this).addTorequestqueue(stringRequest);
        }
```

**And this is my MySingleton class**

```
    private MySingleton (Context context){
    ctx = context;
    requestQueue = getRequestQueue();
}

public static synchronized  MySingleton getmInstance(Context context){
    if (mInstance == null){
        mInstance = new MySingleton(context);
    }
    return mInstance;
}

public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {

    if (requestQueue == null){
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(ctx.getApplicationContext());
    }
    return requestQueue;
}
public <T> void addTorequestqueue(Request<T> request ){

    requestQueue.add(request);
}
```

Comment: if you'll see your getParams method you're returning params hashmap which is of type <String, String> that is why it is only sending the string value

Comment: Most of the back-end languages are dynamically typed so that if you are sending one as string 1 there is no problem with that. You can do all the operations you want.

Comment: Yeah I knew that, I am getting only String because I am returning it, but how can I return integer value or can get it? Please provide me some solution with code, taking my code as a reference and also specify that where should I have to change it in my code...